# Ionic Transparent Nav Bar in one view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to get the nav bar to become transparent in a one view. However I'm having trouble doing that.

Here's my menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable" ng-class="clear">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Here's my menu controller

```
  $rootScope.$on('noNavBar', function(){
    $scope.clear = 'bar-light';
    console.log($scope.clear);
  });
```

Here's the css

```
.bar.bar-light {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.66) !important;  or transparent, or background:none
}

.scroll-content {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Is it because the nav bar is cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to hide nav-bar in a specific view use `hide-nav-bar="true"` inside `<ion-view>`.

If you need to customize nav-bar (i.e. apply a specific class) add an `<ion-nav-bar>` tag inside the `<ion-view>` you want with a custom nav bar:

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="right" class="bar-positive">...</ion-nav-bar>
```

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/XXeydY